# SyntaxNet to process a large number of sentences, do GPUs increase performance?

Tags: syntax, tensorflow, nlp, gpu

I have a large dataset of sentences (i.e., ~5.000.000) in raw text which I want to process using SyntaxNet already trained for English. That is, I just want to process the sentences using a SyntaxNet model, I don't want to train any new model.

Setting up a processing environment with GPUs will have any effect on performance ?

I understand that most of the heavy CPU operations is on estimating the parameters and weights of the network/model, once these are estimated, applying the trained network should be faster than training.

Nevertheless, I've never worked before with Tensorflow and I don't know whether GPUs are used when one applies an already trained model to data.

Also, does anyone knows any easy way to setup SyntaxNet as a daemon or web-service, so that batch processing can be made easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to do a lot of tensor operations on the graph to predict something. So GPU still provides performance improvement for inference. Take a look at this [nvidia paper](https://www.nvidia.com/content/tegra/embedded-systems/pdf/jetson_tx1_whitepaper.pdf), they have not tested their stuff on TF, but it is still relevant:

> Our results show that GPUs provide state-of-the-art inference
>   performance and energy efficiency, making them the platform of choice
>   for anyone wanting to deploy a trained neural network in the field. In
>   particular, the Titan X delivers between 5.3 and 6.7 times higher
>   performance than the 16-core Xeon E5 CPU while achieving 3.6 to 4.4
>   times higher energy efficiency.

Regarding how to deploy your model, take a look at [TF serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/)